# JavaScript success message disappear

Tags: javascript, firebase

HTML button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="addBtn" onclick="addfunction();">Add</button>
```

addfunction() code:

```
    var title = document.getElementById("TitleInput").value;

var ID = firebase.database().ref().child('emp').push().key;
//upload pic

var filename = selectionfile;
filename = newsID;
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(filename);
var uploadTask = storageRef.put(selectionfile);

if (user != null) {
    userid = user.uid;

    var Dataa = {
        ID: ID,
        title: title,
    };

    var updates = {};
    updates['/emp/' + ID] = Dataa;
    var returnUpdate = firebase.database().ref().update(updates);

    if (returnUpdate) {
        var mess = document.getElementById("confirm_mess");
        mess.setAttribute("class", "bg-success h4");
        mess.setAttribute("style", "padding: 1%; margin: 1% 9% 0 35%");
        mess.innerHTML = "done";

    }
}
```

}
and this is the validation code

```
$(function () {
$("#title_span").hide();

var error_title = false;

$("#TitleInput").focusout(function () {
    Title_validation();
});


function Title_validation() {
    var title = $("#TitleInput").val();

    if (title == "") {
        $("#title_span").html("wrong input");
        $("#title_span").show();
        error_title = true;
    }
    else {
        $("#title_span").hide();
    }

}


$("#my_form").submit(function () {
    error_title = false;

    Title_validation();

    if (error_title == false) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

});
```

});

my problem is, when i click the add button, "done" message disappear immediately because the refreshing, i want the message to appear for few second and then refresh the page. how can i do that? knowing that i try to use `setTimeout` but it does not work.

Comment: You mention that the message disappears because of a page refresh. But the code you shared doesn't show how that page refresh is triggered. This makes it hard to help you delay the refresh. The general approach will be similar to what Sentry posted, but please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a more tailored answer.

Comment: I change my code and add the validation code, may this is what trigger the refreshing @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: It's still hard to be certain what goes wrong. But one thing you should to is prevent the default behavior in your click handler. `$("#my_form").submit(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); `. Also see the [jQuery documentation for `submit()`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Answer (score 1):

Change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Answer (score 1):

If your button has to submit a form remove the `type="submit"`, change the `<button>` tag to `<a>` and change your code to the following. You also have to add an ID to your form:

```
<script>
addfunction() {

    var title = document.getElementById("TitleInput").value;

var ID = firebase.database().ref().child('emp').push().key;

if (user != null) {
    userid = user.uid;

    var Dataa = {
        ID: ID,
        title: title,
    };

    var updates = {};
    updates['/emp/' + ID] = Dataa;
    var returnUpdate = firebase.database().ref().update(updates);

    if (returnUpdate) {
        var mess = document.getElementById("confirm_mess");
        mess.setAttribute("class", "bg-success h4");
        mess.setAttribute("style", "padding: 1%; margin: 1% 9% 0 35%");
        mess.innerHTML = "done";

    }
setTimeout(function () { //wait 5 seconds
document.getElementById(yourForm).submit; //submit your form
    }, 5000);
}

}
</script>
```

OR show the message after everything is send. I think you use a form to submit your data. just add to your `<form>` `action=?done=true`
Then you call the script if the variable 'done' is true:

```
<?php
if (isset($done)) {
echo "<script>your script</script>"; //or do whatever you want if the var is true
}
```

?>

Comment: @Fatima36 please show me your coding of the side and not only the button. That would help to get a solution. And try to change the <button> tag to <a> like I wrote above.

Comment: this solution stop refreshing, and I want the page to be refresh after the message appear. @Sentry